# I mistakenly got a 2nd and a 3rd "Marshall" bagde

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

Yesterday I got 2 new messages saying:

> You've earned the "Marshal" badge (Raise 500 helpful flags).

I've already earned a Marshal badge and I thought you could earn this only once. Since I do not have 1000 helpful flags or more, I couldn't have gotten a 2nd one or even a 3rd.

I should have 8 Gold Badges, but it now shows **10** :D

This can't be right... Is this a bug?

See the weirdness here all summed up in one screen (and beautiful drawings included):

[image]

Comment: Whaaat? Free gold badges. I want those. I think the Marshal badge can be earned only once. So I guess this is a bug. I think we should summon @Pops in here to clear this up.

Comment: SMELT THEM INTO MONEY!

Comment: Unfortunately back to 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. I found something.
Apparently SE devs screw up from time to time :)
[Excavator and Marshal badges are being awarded over and over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280023/224252)